# What is 'Primitive' attribute in Crystal-lang?

Tags: crystal-lang

While reading Crystal-lang internal code, I came across to some snippet like:

```
@[Primitive(:some_name)]
def some_method
end
```

May anyone explain me what the `Primitive` attribute does and how it works (eg. tells the compiler to use a LLVM function)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is functionality that cannot be expressed in pure Crystal. Any time a call to such a method appears, it needs to be replaced with low-level instructions ([LLVM IR](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#abstract)) directly by the compiler, rather than being backed by an actual function.

This is needed because some operations are already at the lowest level. For example, how do you implement the addition of two numbers? Uhh, `a+b`? Wait, but that's what we're trying to implement. So, other than resorting to ridiculous things like `if a==1 && b==1 ...` this needs to be deferred to the CPU (through [LLVM IR](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#abstract)).

The file [primitives.cr](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/master/src/primitives.cr) contains only empty shells of such methods, and also the documentation for them, so they look like a normal part of the standard library. They are marked by an annotation for the compiler to know when to replace them. And the real action happens in [compiler/crystal/codegen/primitives.cr](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/master/src/compiler/crystal/codegen/primitives.cr): there's a `case` branch for each annotation name, which leads to code that generates appropriate code.

For completeness, here's an excerpt from [primitives.cr](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/master/src/primitives.cr):

> Methods defined here are primitives because they either:
>
> - can't be expressed in Crystal (need to be expressed in LLVM). For example unary
>     and binary math operators fall into this category.
> - should always be inlined with an LLVM instruction for performance reasons, even
>     in non-release builds. An example of this is `Char#ord`, which could be implemented
>     in Crystal by assigning `self` to a variable and casting a pointer to it to `Int32`,
>     and then reading back the value.

---

Side note:
This is not the only way that the compiler has for implementing methods that can't be normal stdlib methods. This also happens for pseudo-methods like `obj.is_a?`, [on a syntactic level](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/202e5ac7f8c57632a6914aec3474bf9c7720e07c/src/compiler/crystal/syntax/parser.cr#L612). This is an even "stronger" ability, and the pretense of it being a method is dropped (you won't find `is_a?` in [Object's documentation](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.26.0/Object.html)). This kind of construct is tied deeply into the compiler and can [affect type information](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/if_varis_a.html).

Comment: Great answer! Given that this was never explained, it's truly awesome that you was able to explain it so thoroughly.

Comment: It's actually not that difficult to dig into it, asterite. The code is relatively easy to understand and documented enough. =)